# Method not found: 'Void System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity..ctor(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

I'm migrating a site from one web server running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard to one IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2. I'm currently receiving the message below. I know System.Security.Claims is supposed to be in the mscorlib.dll and that seems to be in place. I'm not really certain what else would be helpful in even asking this question, but if anyone has ideas to point me in the right direction, that would be great! Thanks!

> **Server Error in '/profile' Application.**

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity..ctor(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)'.
```

> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Void
>   System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity..ctor(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)'.
>
> **Source Error:**

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

> **Stack Trace:**

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity..ctor(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)'.] 
System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity..ctor(FormsIdentity identity) +0             
System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity.Clone() +35    
System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal.AddIdentityWithRoles(IIdentity identity, String[] roles) +57
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticate(FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e) +338    
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +88    
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
+80    
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +161
```

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1

Comment: Explaining what your application does, describing a specific scenario, and posting some code could be helpful. All I know is that you are "migrating" your site.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with it. I realize I'm grasping at straws here. This particular message shows up when I try to log in. I'll see if I can pick out relevant code, but a lot of it is compiled and I don't have the original source.

Comment: I'm less familiar with it than you, and I don't have the source. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue in one of our windows 2012 r2 servers. MVC applications built using forms identity were throwing errors.

We found out that a particular Microsoft update patch **(KB3098785)** was causing the issue.

We unistalled the patch, rebooted the server ans  voila..everything was running fine

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three causes:

1. You've missed a DLL that the application needs. Maybe a library or framework needs to be installed onto the server.
2. Maybe your two servers are running different versions of the .NET framework. Check both servers and see what versions they have, all the details are found on this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
3. It might be a security/permissions thing. Try changing the app pool in IIS to run as an admin, and if the problem goes away, it's a permissions problem.